# Regular expression match any single character at any postion except at the begining after certain letter

Tags: regex

I've got a problem while matching via regular expression. For example:

`UL`**U**FDSG**U**

This means I have to accept all `U` characters axcept starting with `UL`.

**U**SDSG**U**FDSG**U**

e.g. I'm a not able to match beginng after `L`.

```
U(?!^(UL))+ // matching every U
```

Comment: This is not clear. Can you post multiple strings that should and should not match? That way we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Also, can you make the question and problem more clear so we can properly understand the issue you're experiencing

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, though, you can use `(?!^UL)U`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `^U(?!L)|(?<!^)U`:

- `^U(?!L)` matches letter U at the beginning of the string but not followed by `L`;
- `(?<!^)U` matches letter U that's not at the beginning of the string;

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WzbmnK/1/).

Or a simpler one `(?!^UL)U`, firstly assert the string does not start with `UL`, then match the letter U.

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/WzbmnK/2/)